# How to display database content in a modal form using ajax datatables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

I want to display data from a database in a Bootstrap modal using datatables.

Here is the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cartModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form>
            <div class="modal-body">
                    <table class="table table-responsive table-borderless" id="cart-content">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    </table>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now im using datatables to display it, and ajax so that the page does not need to reload to update the contents.

```
function cart_contents() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "cartContents.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            $('#cart-content').dataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "scrollX": false,
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"sTitle": "Product", "mData": "product"},
                    {"sTitle": "Price", "mData": "price"},
                    {"sTitle": "Qty.", "mData": "quantity"}
                ]
            })
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert('Failed');
        }
    })
}
```

Here's the button that triggers the modal:

```
<button class="d-none d-sm-inline-block btn btn-xl btn-primary shadow-sm" data-target="#cartModal" data-toggle="modal">View Cart</button>
```

And here's my cartContents.php:

```
<?php
include_once('../db.php');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cart");
if($stmt->execute()){
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output[] = array("id"=>$row['ID'], "product"=>$row['name'], "quantity"=>$row['quantity'], "price"=>$row['price']);
    }
echo json_encode($output);
}
$stmt->close();
```

However, i can't seem to display the contents on the modal. I don't know what seems to be the problem.

Comment: Did you call the `cart_contents()` function? You should call it before you open the modal.

Comment: I did a few edits and added an onclick event to the button that opens the modal. Few parts of the datatable appeared, but not the data (columns and rows) itself. And, whenever I close the modal and click the button again, it throws a warning that says cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: Can you share the JSON response from cartContents.php?

Comment: Which version of DataTables do you use?